# Family re-unification visa processing time

Tags: european-union, germany, immigration, family-law, visa

Is there anything in immigration law in Germany which enforces that a family re-unification visa process should be finished maximum in a defined interval?

I am from Afghanistan and having EU Blue-Card. My wife and children applied for the appointment in German embassy on March 2021, now it is 7 months the embassy didn't gave the appointment for interview and they are telling it will take about two years to reach my wife's turn.

In this case, do I have the right to challenge this decision of embassy or any law which regulate this?

Comment: I don't think the legislature of Germany would be okay with such a poor idea. If the immigration department cannot make a useful decision within whatever time is mandated, do you expect they'd do something other than give a flat rejection? Immigration takes as long as it takes to resolve, telling them to hurry up when they've got enormous amounts of information to sort through on every application will only result in fewer approvals or more "false positive/negative" outcomes.

Comment: That make sense, but unfortunately they separate the families by doing so. No idea what to do.